# Caches of all versions of a webapp deployed in parallel are shutdowned

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache

I use ehcache in a webapp whose versions are [deployed in parallel](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) on a Tomcat instance. This is a handy way to deploy new versions without stopping an application.

I however have a problem with this way to proceed : even if I give the cache and disk store different names, depending on the versions of the webapp, **all** caches are stopped when stopping **one** instance.

My config is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" name="mywebapp-${project.version}_build_${buildNumber}">
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    statistics="true"
/>

<cache
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
    name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false"
    statistics="true"/>

<cache
    name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false"
    statistics="true"/>

<cache
    name="query.Presences"
    maxElementsInMemory="100"
    maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskPersistent="false"
    statistics="true"/>

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/mywebapp-${project.version}_build_${buildNumber}"/> 

</ehcache>
```

`${project.version}` and `${buildNumber}`

being replaced by maven during the build process.

Does someone know how to avoid this unwanted behaviour ?

I am using ehcache-core-2.4.3 and hibernate-ehcache-4.3.8.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong in guessing but should not be `diskPersistence` set to true. I don't know the internals of EhCache but if the caches are only held in memory and you shut down one instance (in the same JVM because it is still one tomcat instance) it sounds right that the cache is cleared.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the doc states :

diskPersistent : 
«For caches that overflow to disk, whether the disk cache persists between CacheManager instances.»

false is the behaviour I desire.

Comment: I don't know where to find complete docs for ecache 2.4 but I got my information from http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/fast-restart / section "Compatibility with Previous Versions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.ShutdownListener` works is by shutting down *ALL* cache managers.

So the only way for this to work for you is by making sure your cache managers end up in different class loaders, that is ehcache is loaded by the web application class loader and not the container one.

Do you provide ehcache jar in your app's `WEB-INF/lib`? If yes, are you sure there is not an Ehcache in tomcat's classpath?

If this solution still does not work, you may be better off creating your own `ServletContextListener` that would shutdown only the cache manager from the containing application.

Comment: I provide ehcache in tomcat/lib. Your explanation is interesting. I will test on Monday. As hibernate stops its ehcache instance, I might end just safely shut down hibernate, and nothing else.

Comment: You were right, I gladly gives you the 50 reputation points. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some details are missing from your query.

1)How are you stopping the cache?

2)How are you deploying application in tomcat?

3)Have you checked the location where does the cache object is created ?

But as a behavior all cache will cleared once you restart tomcat.

Comment: 1) The cache is stopped by the net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.ShutdownListener listener.
2) The application is deployed by dropping the war in the webapps/ dir. Then, is is autodeployed because of Tomcat config.
3) Maybe I do not fully understand your question, but each version uses its separate diskstore, and things are written there. Should I look something else ?